# How to use Fixed data table with inconsistent data

Tags: reactjs, fixed-data-table

This are my Offers and i want to display them in my Fixed-Data-Table.
There if the Offer is Global der is no Entry in the Data.

```
{
  "id" : "90528630948ijvehiddwid",
  "name" : "Some Offer In Germany",
  "updatedTime" : "2016-01-15T13:24:26.090Z",
  "createdTime" : "2016-01-15T09:37:12.396Z",
  "country" : {
    "code" : "DE",
    "name" : "Germany"
  }
},
{
  "id" : "589476350240ß358540a",
  "name" : "Some Global In Offer",
  "updatedTime" : "2016-01-15T13:24:26.090Z",
  "createdTime" : "2016-01-15T09:37:12.396Z"
}
```

I Want to have a Custom Cell that displays a "Global" if there is no Country available. But i see the problem is in the Table it self because it can not build a cell if there is no entry...

```
var CountryCell = ({rowIndex, data, col, ...props}) => (
    <Cell {...props}>
      {col ? data[rowIndex][col] : 'Global' }
    </Cell>
);

<Column
            columnKey="country"
            header={<Cell>country</Cell>}
            footer={<Cell className='backgroud-blue'></Cell>}
            cell={<CountryCell data={this.state.offers} col="country"/>}
            fixed={false}
            width={250}
            isResizable={false}
          />
```

So what is the best approach for such a case. Do i Build a wrapper around my raw data and "fake" that cases which do not have a country object ?

Answer (score 0):

I think changes below might work for just showing "Global" in case of missing object,

```js
var CountryCell = ({rowIndex, data, col, ...props}) => (
    <Cell {...props}>
      { data[rowIndex][col] ? data[rowIndex][col] : 'Global' }
    </Cell>
);
```